# Can .ajax() handle multiple returned values separated by a few seconds?

Tags: jquery, ajax

If the receiver of ajax post acts like this:

```
// process/te_bulk.php

$jsonList = '[{"AV"},{"QT"}]';
echo $jsonList;

sleep ( 5 )              // or, continue curl request for jsonList variable 1

$jsonArray = '[{"1","15","JOG"},{"2","20","RUN"}]';
echo $jsonArray;

sleep ( 4 )              // or, continue curl request for jsonList variable 2

$jsonArray = '[{"1","25","SWIM"},{"2","30","BIKE"}]';
echo $jsonArray;
```

First attempt - **Delays XHR loading for 5 seconds with both strings arriving appended, at the same time**, which results in 'Invalid JSON':

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process/te_bulk.php",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: { user: "12345" }
}).success(function( msg ) {
  var string = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
  alert( "Data Returned: "+string );
});
```

Can the .post() or .ajax() respond to each echo separately? Loading the page process/te_bulk.php in a browser gives the 5 & 4 second delays. In other words, how to populate a page with data as it becomes available, instead of receiving all data when te_bulk.php finishes processing.

An alternative appears to: Have 2 .ajax() functions, one for receiving the first string, processing and calling the second function, as necessary, for the $jsonArray data.

If this is not possible, is there another simply way to display a 'progress' indicator of obtained data?

Comment: Why don't you return a json array with all values ?

Comment: No, it will only parse the results when the readystate is 4 (complete). As far as a progress indicator, again, that is a no, unless you want to implement a process to track it.

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault Because it might take 15 seconds for ALL the results and my desire is for the progress to be displayed. The 'data' is coming from curl requests.

Comment: Ok, it won't work that way, you'll have to handle each curl request separatly.

Comment: @David you can make Ajax Call Synced by passing Async : False and than you can control the execute order.

Comment: @KevinB Your's is the best answer so far. Can you make it an answer? .ajax() cannot handle it via one request, but CAN with 2.

Comment: @Burmi The jQuery documentation for .ajax() suggests to 'avoid' doing that because it may 'hang' the browser.

Comment: @David that is true, but only that way you can take control of code execution and prevent race condition if 2 functions are writing to the same variable

Comment: @Burimi In this case, it won't matter if browser is hung. The user needs to wait for all data to be gathered before acting on it. I will look into this.

Comment: @David If you use async: false, it will be hung for 9 seconds in thise case, not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax will only enter a "complete" state when the readystate is 4. If you were to flush the buffer (which would send any already returned content to the browser) the content would be sent to the browser, however, *jQuery will not parse it until the readystate becomes 4*.

With that last part in mind, If you still want to pursue this, check whether or not the responseText is being updated with the content from the ajax reqeust as it's being flushed.

You would have to update you php to flush the buffer after each record.

Comment: In comment to Justin, viewing process/te_bulk.php in a browser results in 1st variable, 5 second delay, 2nd variable, 4 second delay, 3rd variable. The script has no ob_flush(), although maybe php.ini

Comment: Yes, that means it is flushing. In that case, test whether the same is being seen in the responseText property of the jqXHR by inspecting it every second or so and logging it to the console.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll need a few to develop that. (still learning jQuery)

Comment: `var jqXHR = $.ajax(...); setInterval(function(){console.log(jqXHR.responseText);},1000);` though, it of course will keep running. ideally you'd stop the interval when the request is done.

Answer (score 1):

The echo does not return anything to the client, so the sample code above will not do what you want.  If you want to load parts of your page asynchronously than you must use a separate ajax call for each part.

See Kevin's comment below, as the buffer may be flushed out to the client part way through a request.

Comment: Might be important to note that it is possible to return "parts" of a page before the entire page is done processing by flushing the buffer, however ajax still won't enter a complete state until the entire page is returned.

Comment: Justin, I disagree with the first sentence. The script IS returning something. From ajax, the return is delayed 5 seconds from send and the 2 php json variables are echoed one-behind-the-other. In a browser, the processing script echos the 2nd variable after a 5 second delay.

Comment: @David That is only true if php is flushing the buffer after an echo. I don't know if it is or not.

Comment: @David, as Kevin said, you would have to adjust your code to flush the buffer and effectively return data to the client before you continue on to the next echo.   When you see the data being returned to the client, do you see all 3 echo's respond at the same time, or does it honor the "sleeps" between them?

Comment: Without ob_flush(), it honors the 'sleep', only when viewing the receiving file in a browser. Using .ajax(), the alert is delayed 9 seconds after sending.

Comment: @David - I see, that is bizarre.

Comment: I suspect it is 'another of those things that are hidden from my view', like so much about computers and coding... :)